# Overfull boxes with fncychap's Bjornstrup: How can I remove a vertical line in chapter the title?

Tags: chapters, boxes, fncychap

I'd like to remove the vertical line next to the chapter number, but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion?

[image: Next to Chapter Number there's a vertical line which I don't want and I don't know how to remove it]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the `draft` option from the `\documentclass` line. The `fncychap` style you're using makes an overfull box. Please add minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bjornstrup` option for `fncychap` implements the shifting of the number in the wrong way, producing an overfull box (if the `draft` option for the class is active, this overfull box will be marked by the black line showed in the image in the question).

You can correct the problem by redefining `\DOCH` and using `\rlap` instead of the default `\hbox` used in the `Bjornstrup` style:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}      % Amount of space by which the
%                                  % number is shifted right
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbox[gray]{.85}{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \rlap{\color[gray]{.5}\CNoV\thechapter}\\%
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I just left the `draft` option to show that the overfull box warning is now avoided.

As a final personal suggestion, have you considered using another style for your chapter titles?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! No, I didn't consider another style for the chapter titles, do you think it is not the best one? Or do you think there's some other style better to use? Thanks!