# Blocked number of chapter/section by hyperref only in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, chapters

I have recently discovered, that I can't move from hyperref connected with number of chapter/section in table of contents to a page, where the chapter/section is - it look as it blocked... Actually, I can move from the number, which is present in the main text. What could I do to make it work here and here?

[image: Current situation (1)]

[image: Current situation (2)]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry} %marginesy
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %kodowanie polskich znaków
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\babelprovide[transforms = oneletter.nobreak]{polish} %brak wiszących liter na końcu zdania
\selectlanguage{polish}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft} %nowoczesny spis treści
\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\hfil}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hfil}

\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.} %kropki po numerze rozdziału
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.} %kropki po numerze sekcji
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\bfseries} %numer pogrubiony przy rozdziale
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}} %kropki przy rozdziałach w spisie treści
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1cm} %odstęp między kropką a nazwą rozdziału w spisie treści
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\large} %duża czcionka rozdziału
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\Large}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[nottoc, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight, pagebackref, linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap} %nowoczesny wygląd rozdziału

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother %zabezpieczenie przed tworzeniem nowej strony przed rozdziałem

%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\hyperref[toc]{\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\hyperref[toc]{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}}

\makeatletter
\let\sv@endpart\@endpart
\def\@endpart{\thispagestyle{empty}\sv@endpart}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\oldchapter\chapter
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\oldchapter*{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter*[..]{...}
        {\IfValueTF{#2}
            {\oldchapter[#2]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter[..]{...}
            {\oldchapter[#3]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter{...}
            %\label{chapter-\thechapter}% \label this chapter
        }%
    }
    
    \let\oldsection\section
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\oldsection*{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}
        {\IfValueTF{#2}
            {\oldsection[#2]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}
            {\oldsection[#3]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}
            %\label{section-\thesection}
        }%
    }
    
    \let\oldpart\part
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\part}{s o m}{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\oldpart*{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}
        {\IfValueTF{#2}
            {\oldpart[#2]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}
            {\oldpart[#3]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}
            \label{part-\thepart}
        }%
    }
}

\hbadness=99999
\hfuzz=100.002pt

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents\label{toc}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    
    \setcounter{part}{0}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{part}}
    \part*{\texorpdfstring{\vspace*{2cm} Część I \\[-1.5cm] Część pierwsza}{Część pierwsza}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{I. Część pierwsza}{Część pierwsza}}
    
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \chapter{Rozdział 1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{5}
    \lipsum[1]
    \stepcounter{figure}
    \cftaddtitleline{lof}{figure}{\large Ryc. \textbf{\thefigure.} Napis}{\textbf{\thepage}}
    \begin{figure}[h!] 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} 
        \caption*{Napis}
    \end{figure}
    \section{Sekcja 1}
    \lipsum[2]
    \stepcounter{figure}
    \cftaddtitleline{lof}{figure}{\large Ryc. \textbf{\thefigure.} Napis 2}{\textbf{\thepage}}
    \stepcounter{figure}
    \cftaddtitleline{lof}{figure}{\large Ryc. \textbf{\thefigure.} Napis 3}{\textbf{\thepage}}
   \newpage
  
    \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't redefine `\thechapter` and `\thesection` to add links. These commands are used in various places and should expand to normal text. For the sectioning number redefine `\@seccntformat` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308737/seccntformat-only-for-section) and for the chapter redefine `\DOCH` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133064/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okey, okey... but when I do this, the links from number of chapters are being dissapered... The proof: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ytnnqmybrvxd

Comment: sorry but I don't debug external overleaf projects.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmm... How can I show you current situation? In the answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry for making the problem, if it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't redefine `\thechapter` and `\thesection` to add links. Instead redefine the chapter number by redefining the command from fncychap:

```
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}      % Amount of space by which the
%                                  % number is shifted right
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbox[gray]{.85}{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\color[gray]{.5}\CNoV\hyperref[toc]{\thechapter}}\\%<<<---
  }
```

And to add a link to section numbers redefine `\@seccntformat`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname sec#1numberformat\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname}\quad}
\newcommand\secsectionnumberformat[1]{\hyperref[toc]{#1}}
\makeatother
```

(I don't think that these links are useful. I don't like it if documents have too many active areas, as you then have to be careful not to click on or touch a screen as it can move you to unwanted places. If I want to go to the toc I use the bookmarks.).

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I wanted! And sorry for making a trouble!